# Symfony ContextListener - huge memory usage

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with symfony 4.4 + PHP 7.4 and memory usage. There is a form with several fields and when it is submitted the server throws a 502 error or Symfony error page (various). Error related to memory overflow in ContextListener class.

The code of the controller handling the form is:

```
$this->addFlash('success', 'Wysłano komunikat');
return $this->redirectToRoute('prpo_msg_list');
```

and from what I diagnosed, the flash message writes correctly (so the previous code executes correctly), then an error is thrown. If at this point I call the address from the 'prpo_msg_list' route, it loads correctly + I can see the flash message added earlier.

I also did another test. Locally, I raised the memory limit for this action to 1024M and commented out the redirect line. As a result, the action of the post is performed but there is no redirection, so I can see the profiler. At the time of loading an empty form, the memory consumption shown by the profiler ranges from **20-40MB** (with a different refresh rate), while after sending the form by post it is ... **400MB**.

Displaying information from the Symfony profiler, I can see that the greatest increase in memory is recorded in **debug.security.authorization.vote** (a jump by several hundred mega).

Going further: the memory is exceeded in the ContextListener class on the line:

```
    $session->set($this->sessionKey, serialize($token));
```

I dumped the contents of $token onto the screen and noticed that the user object contains, among others all messages (short in text, about 20, so not crazy) and I went in this direction. In the entity I can see:

```
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Module\PricesPolicy\Entity\PrpoMessage", inversedBy="receivers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="prpo_receiver",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cms_auth_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prpo_message_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $prpoMessage;
```

It takes about **40 seconds** for the $token dump to be displayed. When I comment on the fragment related to @ORM\JoinTable, it is **3 seconds**. Well, deleting this fragment causes further errors in the application.

Have any of you encountered such a phenomenon? Where to find the reason for such a huge consumption of memory?

Comment: Hi, see this solution: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but with no result :(